# Edição de perguntas ou repostas. Todas as contribuições são licenciadas pela Creative Commons. O que significa isso?

Tags: suporte, edição

Vi no site da Central de Ajuda o seguinte texto sobre edição de perguntas ou repostas "[Todas as contribuições são licenciadas pela Creative Commons](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)". O que significa isso? Qual seria o tipo de licença?

Comment: De acordo com o seguinte post, a licença vigente desde fevereiro de 2016 é a MIT: [Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/3117)  Mas agora não tenho certeza se isso entrou em vigou ou não. Nesse outro post você pode ver uma explicação mais aprofundada sobre a cc by-sa 3.0: [Eu posso utilizar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas do SOpt para fazer trabalhos de faculdade?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4777/3117)